# starting and killing threads at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have say two threads t1 and t2 which I want to start at the same time (simultaneously), each call `System.out.println()` to print to console, and then to finish at the same time.

Please advise how to achieve this can it be achieve through executor framework. I am trying to do it with the help of executor framework itself..!!

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain _why_ you want to do this?  Is this a homework question or something?

Comment: have you tried anything yet? if so, show us!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use 2 `CountDownLatch`es or a `CyclicBarrier` to do that. For example:

```
final CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(2);
final CountDownLatch end = new CountDownLatch(2);

Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            start.countDown();
            start.await();
            System.out.println("In 1");
            end.countDown();
            end.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //restore interruption status
        }
    }
};
Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            start.countDown();
            start.await();
            System.out.println("In 2");
            end.countDown();
            end.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //restore interruption status
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 Nice dude.  Please consider always doing something with your `InterruptedException` in example code (either quit or re-interrupt) to not perpetuate the catch and forget mentality.

Comment: @Gray Thanks. Yes absolutely the OP's needs to do something with the `InterruptedException`, most likely just reset the interrupted status and exit. I have edited that way.

Comment: @assylias Thanx dude , Please advise how this same thing can be achieved through executor framework..!!

Comment: @RockySinha Not sure what you are asking. Just submit the runnables to your executor...